# Azure "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, ftp

I have an ASP MVC4 site. I have to create a folder on ftp server and I use this code:

```
FtpWebRequest ftpWebRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://mysite.altervista.org/newfolder");
ftpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;       
ftpWebRequest.UsePassive = true;
ftpWebRequest.EnableSsl = true;
ftpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userTest", "psw123456");
ftpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
ftpWebRequest.UseBinary = true;
using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)ftpWebRequest.GetResponse())
 {
  Console.WriteLine("Result: " + resp.StatusCode);
 }
```

When I run my site in localhost everything works fine, but when I Publish my site to Azure Website, it returns me an exception:  "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in."
I think that the problem is not in my code, do I have to change some setting in Azure?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have tried to check some settings in your FTP server? Maybe, the incoming connections are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

remove below 2 lines and try again

```
ftpWebRequest.UsePassive = true;
ftpWebRequest.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, with localhost works, on Azure it returns the same error: “The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.”

Comment: can you try putting your username as "anonymous" and try again @Lelezeus

Comment: Done, but with anonymous user, both localhost and azure don't work

Comment: may be anything useful here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968938/ftpwebrequest-530-error-not-logged-in-issue?rq=1? @Lelezeus

Comment: Thank you, but I have already checked everything about username & passw .. the point is that in localhost everything works (so the credentials are correct) but on azure don't

Comment: Hi all, have you find a way to do this (sending file using FTP from WebJobs or WebApp) ? thanks in advance